# NSIS: How do I uninstall previous version before install new version if programm name is changed?

Tags: installation, nsis, uninstallation

In my program name, which is written to the registry, there is a version number (for example, it looks like this: "My program 3.1"). I need to uninstall the old installation when installing newer versions 3.2 or 3.3 (and so on), but I do not know how to make the installer find the previous installation in the registry by the version number. Yes, I learned the sample of this link: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Auto-uninstall_old_before_installing_new But in this example, the registry search is performed by the program name. In my case, the name of the program changes, because the version number has changed and the installer can no longer find this entry in the registry to uninstall the old version before installing the new version. Tell me, please, how can I do this.

Here is my sample code:

```
;Define main variables:
!define PRODUCT_NAME "My programm"
!define PRODUCT_VERSION "3.9"
!define PRODUCT_FULLNAME "${PRODUCT_NAME} ${PRODUCT_VERSION}"
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_FULLNAME}"
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY "HKLM"
!define PRODUCT_UNINSTALL_EXE "uninstall.exe"

;Registry is added by this:
WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "UninstallString" '"$INSTDIR\${PRODUCT_UNINSTALL_EXE}" _?=$INSTDIR'

;Read the registry key value for uninstall previous installation:
ReadRegStr $R0 ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "UninstallString"
StrCmp $R0 "" done
```

But this command can not find an entry in the registry, since the name of the program $ {PRODUCT_FULLNAME} already has a different version number.
Please, tell me how to make the entry in the registry look only for the name of the program "My program" and did not take into account the version number?

**Important addition!**

In the message above, I forgot to clarify one thing: my installer is made for a plug-in that is installed in several versions of 3ds Max. As a result, the entry in the registry looks like this: for one version of "My program 3.1 for 3dsMax 2014", and for another version of "My program 3.1 for 3dsMax 2018". And after installing a new version of my program, the entries should look like this: "My program 3.2 for 3dsMax 2014" and "My program 3.2 for 3dsMax 2018". That is, only the version number of my program should change, and everything else ("My program ..." and "... for 3dsMax (version of 3ds Max)" should remain the same.
Thank you for understanding and thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: UninstallString does not normally require the _?= parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `EnumRegKey` to enumerate the uninstall keys:

```
Section
StrLen $3 "${PRODUCT_NAME}"
StrCpy $0 0
loop:
EnumRegKey $1 ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" $0
    StrCmp $1 "" done
    IntOp $0 $0 + 1
    StrCpy $2 $1 $3 ; Get ${PRODUCT_NAME} prefix
    StrCmp $2 "${PRODUCT_NAME}" 0 loop
    ReadRegStr $2 ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\$1" UninstallString
    StrCmp $2 "" loop
    ExecWait $2 ; (This assumes you stored the old versions with the _?= parameter)
    Goto loop
done:
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I forgot to clarify one point, what did the additional message above.

Comment: The `StrCpy $2 $1 $3` line can be changed, $3 can just be a number if the start of the name is always the same and it is the same as "${PRODUCT_NAME}".